# PHP only logging first to Windows event log; requires iisreset in order to log more events

Tags: php, windows, iis

I'm running PHP 7.3 on IIS on Windows 2016 Server. php.ini  is set to direct error_log to syslog. This works fine for the first request, but subsequent requests require an iisreset before only a single event is logged again. Repeat process. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Turning on `display_errors` can you see any warnings or what not about that logging failure perhaps? This also might be useful: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2908246, see dagmar's response.

Comment: you can try to set php error log setting as fastcgi.logging = 0, fastcgi.impersonate = 1,log_errors = On,error_reporting = E_ALL in php.ini file and enable detailed error message in iis. you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php#phpini-file-settings) documnet how to configure php in iis.[Display PHP Errors in IIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7s)make sure you do chnages in right version of the php.ini file.

Comment: Could you share the snapshot of the error message or warning which you get for reset iis?

Comment: Well, there's no error message specific to not being able to log... the strange part is that everything behaves as expected the first time we log an error, but afterward nothing happens in the log even though we can successfully print those errors to the browser. I am wondering if maybe this is a code problem and an undisposed object is blocking the logging until GC picks it up or it is forcibly disposed by the reset. Thoughts on that possibility?

Comment: (Full disclosure: I'm not really a php guy. :) )